# Mono develop create make file for Ubuntu platform

Tags: ubuntu, mono, monodevelop

Is it possible to create a make file that will build a mono developed application.  For example I have a solution file,  and I have project files.  I would like to create a make file that will target either the solution file or project files to build executables.

[image]

Thanks Inadvance

Answer (score 0):

MonoDevelop/Xamarin Studio include a "Makefile Integration" that is located in the *Project Options* Dialog. From there, you can create a simple Makefile or an Autotools version:

[image]

Comment: I am working with Ubuntu and have MonoDevelop installed.  I do not see this feature in the version of MonoDevelop 5.9.6.  Am I doing something incorrect?

Comment: Highlight the Project in the Solution tree, Open Project Option (via right-click "Options" or via main menu.

Comment: Hi RobertN,  please see the image above in my initial post.  I don't see what your seeing.  Do I need to add a package to monodevelop?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: What kind of project are you creating?

Comment: When I launch mono develop,  I create console applications.  So in mono I select file>new>solution>.Net>Console Application